# unable to use pip even after add to environmental variable

Tags: python, pip, windows-10

I'm trying to install `pip` for python 3.6 on windows 10. I run `get-pip.py`. when I try to use pip on terminal I get an error message `Pip command is not recognized`.

I already add `C:\Python36\Scripts` to the environmental variable.

Is there anything I missed ?

Comment: Are you sure python directory is right? Does `python` command work if `C:Python36` is in the environmental variables?

Comment: Which environment variable did you add it to, and what is the new value of that variable?

Comment: And what is `%PATHEXT%`?

Comment: @Daniel H. I add it to `Path`

Comment: @Dadep And the other part of my question: what are the values of `%PATH%` and `%PATHEXT%` now?

Comment: @DanielH. what do you mean by "values" you mean the list of path ?

Comment: Have you missed a \ after `C:` when adding it to your path? Or is it just a typo in your question ?

Comment: yes understood , done

Comment: @Dadep An environment variable is a name, like `%PATH%`, which corresponds to some value like `C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem`. What do you get if you type `echo %PATH%` or `echo %PATHEXT%`?

Comment: get-pip.py is not the preferred way to install pip in Windows Python 3.5+. The installer has an option for this, and also an option to update the environment variables. Just modify your installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved :

the problem is that  python wasn't install in the right place (`C:\python`) but just for one user.

I uninstall and re-install python using "custom" configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check your c:\Python36\scripts\ folder if **pip.exe** is not already installed there?
On Windows, it should be there.

If it is and you did not set any paths, you can start it with the full path

```
"c:\python36\scripts\pip.exe" install yourmodulename
```

Also, when you set the path, open a new cmd windows, as the old one may not realise the path change.